# Uploadify Queue Not Showing

Tags: jquery, html, flash, file-upload, uploadify

I have successfully implemented a copy of uploadify into my site. The SWF button shows, I can click on it and browse my files. However, the rubber meets the road whenever it comes to file files showing the queue.

For some reason, when I select a file, there isn't any queue, even though I have followed uploadify directions. Does anyone have any ideas on how to overcome this? Here are the relative parts of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../system/stylesheets/uploadify.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../system/javascripts/swfobject.js"></script>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="../system/javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../system/javascripts/uploadify.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(':file').uploadify({
    'uploader' : '../system/flash/uploadify.swf',
    'script' : 'index.php',
    'cancelImg' : '../system/images/common/cancel.png'
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
...
<input type="file" name="logo" class="logo" /></td>
...
</body>
</html>
```

I'm sure all of the images/stylesheets/JavaScripts are properly linked, but it is still a no go.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! For some reason, you *MUST* select the input field by it's ID, and therefore, you can't select more than one at a time. (Why??? lol)

Anyway, that solved my problem. Hope that helps someone.